# Use a type parameter in `as` expression inside a generic function

Tags: rust

In the code below the type parameter `T` can only be an integer type.

```rust
fn foo<T>() {
    let _ = 0 as T;
}
```

How to restrict the `T` to make the function to compile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot. But you can use a trait for that, e.g. `u128: From<T>` will accept all integers type. Or you can restrict it to the operations you want to perform on it, e.g. `T: std::ops::Add<Output = T>`.

You can also use the [num-traits](https://lib.rs/crates/num-traits) crate, that defines a bunch of traits for numeric types and operations. E.g. you can use [`num_traits::Num`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/trait.Num.html) trait to accept "anything that is a number", that supports every operation that makes sense. Or [`PrimInt`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/int/trait.PrimInt.html) that additionally supports integer-only operation, such as bitwise operations.

As an example, here's your code with `num_traits::Num`:

```rust
fn foo<T: num_traits::Num>() {
    let _ = T::zero();
}
```

Comment: I realized that I can bound the `T: Default` and use `let _ = T::default()`.

Comment: @nicolai If you only need to get the zero value.

Comment: Note that `u128: From<T>` will only accept unsigned integer types, not all integer types. Also not that this bound won't allow you to create a zero value of type `T`. A better choice would be `T: From<u8>`, which allows all integer types except for `i8`, and enables creating zero values with `T::from(0)`.